# Как в объект с полем List Stops добавить объект TripStop?

Tags: java

Есть вот такой объект

```
 public class Trip
{
    public List<TripStop> Stops;

    public Date CreatedOn;        
    public Double DriverPay;
    public Double Weight; 
........
}
```

Как в него добавить объекты `TripStop`?
`Trip.Stops = ????`

Объект `TripStop` представляет из себя следующее

```
public class TripStop
{
public Integer StopNumber;
public String Notes;
public String SpecialInstructions;
public String LocationHours;
public String LocationDirections;
public String AddressName;
public String Address1;
public String Address2;
.........
}
```

Подскажите, как дальше?

```
    Trip trip = new Trip();
    trip.CreatedOn = DateForDemo("1321386932950");
    trip.DriverPay = 1100.0000;
    trip.Weight = 1000.0000;

    ArrayList<TripStop> tripStops = new ArrayList<TripStop>();
    TripStop tripStop = new TripStop();
    tripStop.Address1 = "";
    tripStop.Address2 = "";
    ........
    tripStops.add(TripStop);

    tripStop = new TripStop();
    tripStop.Address1 = "";
    tripStop.Address2 = "";
    ........
    tripStops.add(TripStop);

    trip.Stops = tripStops//как здесь правильно добавить?
```

Как мне добавить полю `trip.Stops` этот массив `ArrayList<TripStop> tripStops`?

Comment: плохой подход обращяся к поням объекта напрямую, надо делать геттеры и сеттеры, 

>   trip.Stops = tripStops//как здесь
> правильно добавить?

непонятно, что куда тебе надо добавить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Упрощаем. Итак есть классы

```
public class Trip
{
    public List<TripStop> Stops;
}

public class TripStop
{
    public Integer StopNumber;
}
```

Добавляем классы так:

```
TripStop ts = new TripStop();

ts.StopNumber = 0;

List<TripStop> list = new ArrayList<TripStop>();

list.add(ts);
```

И наконец

```
Trip t = new Trip();

t.Stops = list;
```

Comment: помойму, у него тоже самое написано

Comment: Тогда, в чем проблема?

Comment: Большое спасибо Всем!!!!!!!
Я сделал так
trip.Stops = new ArrayList<TripStop>();
 а потом так
trip.Stops.add(tripStop);

Я не сильно разбираюсь, потом попробую Ваш вариант